# Analyzing Pseudo-Code

Tags: algorithm, analysis

I'm going through past papers which my University releases, however for some bizarre reason they do not release exemplar solutions for them.

I was just wondering if I've done the complexity analysis for this piece of pseudo-code correctly.

Here is the pseudo-code (sorry for the imgur link, pdfs messed up the syntax format): https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGst2.png

When I did the analysis I got O(n^4). It's mostly the squaring and cubing of the input in the loops that is confusing me, we did not cover that in class and I can't find any online resources on it.

Comment: Instead of posting a link to an image, it'd be more helpful if you just type what it says. It isn't that much text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "display(i,j)" is done in constant time (or a single operation) and that we don't count any cost for incrementing variables, then the total cost is:

N*((N^3 - 4) + (N^2 + 1)) = N^4 +N^3 - 3N

You are correct that it is O(N^4).  This is because (for large enough N) N^4 + N^3 - 3N <= 2N^4.

Comment: Yep, sorry, I should have mentioned it - it is indeed done in constant time. 

The working out seems to match what I did on paper too, so thanks again for your reply, that is reassuring that I am on the right track for solving these kind of problems!